# Exclamation mark conflicts with EnableDelayedExpansion in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have the following piece of code in a batch file with the option EnableDelayedExpansion on:

```
::
:: Split
::
for /F "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /s /b *.cue') do (
    pushd .
    cd %%~dpF
    mkdir out
    cd out

    :: Set input file
    set inFile=
    if exist "%%~dpnF.flac" (
        set inFile="%%~dpnF.flac"
    ) else (
        if exist "%%~dpnF" (
            set inFile="%%~dpnF"
        ) else (
            set inFile="%%~dpF*.flac"
        )
    )

    shntool.exe split -f "%%F" -t %%t -o flac -m /-?':' !inFile!

    echo %ERRORLEVEL%
    if %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1 (
        rmdir /q out   
    )
    popd
)
```

The code shown searches for .cue - .flac pairs (cd rips) recursively in the current directory and splits them using the shntool. The problem arises when some directory name contains an exlamation mark (!) that conflicts with the EnableDelayedExpansion option and the exlamation mark dissapears from the variable expansion, thus failing on some pairs.

How can i modify this snippet to somehow escape the exlamation marks in the **!inFile!** variable in order to make it work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fetch the value from `%%F` without delayed expansion.
Simply toggle the delayed expansion mode in each loop.

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /s /b *.cue') do (
    set "directory=%%~dpF"
    set "file=%%~dpnF"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    pushd .
    cd !directory!
    mkdir out
    cd out

    :: Set input file
    set inFile=
    if exist "!file!.flac" (
        set inFile="!file!.flac"
    ) else (
        if exist "!file!" (
            set inFile="!file!"
        ) else (
            set inFile="!file!*.flac"
        )
    )

    shntool.exe split -f "%%F" -t %%t -o flac -m /-?':' !inFile!

    echo !ERRORLEVEL!
    if !ERRORLEVEL! GEQ 1 (
        rmdir /q out   
    )
    popd
    endlocal
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try with something like

```dos
::
:: Split
::
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%F in (*.cue) do (

    if exist "%%~dpnF.flac" (
        set "inFile=%%~dpnF.flac"
    ) else if exist "%%~dpnF" (
        set "inFile=%%~dpnF"
    ) else (
        set "inFile=%%~dpF*.flac"
    )

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ("!inFile!") do (
        endlocal
        2>nul md "%%~dpF\out"
        set "shnError="
        pushd "%%~dpF\out" && (
            shntool.exe split -f "%%~fF" -t %%t -o flac -m /-?':' "%%~a" || set "shhError=1"
            popd
        )
        if defined shnError rmdir /s /q "%%~dpF\out"
    )
)
endlocal
```

The basic problem with delayed expansion is handled by disabling it and then using

```dos
....
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("!inFile!") do (
    endlocal
    ....
```

This code is enabling delayed expansion to allow access to the `inFile` variable, stores the value in the `for` replaceable parameter and then disables delayed expansion so the rest of the code is executed with delayed expansion disabled but still being able to retrieve to access the required value using the `for` replaceable parameter.

Answer (score 2):

try this (all calls to the tool are trough subroutine):

```
::
:: Split
::
for /F "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /s /b *.cue') do (
    pushd .
    cd %%~dpF
    mkdir out
    cd out

    :: Set input file
    set inFile=
    if exist "%%~dpnF.flac" (
        rem set inFile="%%~dpnF.flac"
        call :shntool "%%~dpnF.flac"
    ) else (
        if exist "%%~dpnF" (
            rem set inFile="%%~dpnF"
            call :shntool "%%~dpnF"
        ) else (
            rem set inFile="%%~dpF*.flac"
            call :shntool "%%~dpF*.flac"
        )
    )

    rem shntool.exe split -f "%%F" -t %%t -o flac -m /-?':' !inFile!

    echo %ERRORLEVEL%
    if %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1 (
        rmdir /q out   
    )
    popd
)

exit /b 0

:shntool

for /l %%a in (1;1;1) do (
    shntool.exe split -f "%%F" -t %%t -o flac -m /-?':' "%%~1"
)

exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Beware the wrapper for loop in the subroutine.It will make accessible the tokens of the initial loop.